# Tic Tac Toe MVC GAME

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, jbutton, tic-tac-toe

I am trying to create a tic tac toe game according to MVC pattern.
What I do understand is that in view is the grafic content.
In model has all the logic thinking of the game, so for example, whos turn it is, who the winner is and etc...
While controller has the listener function inside.

But What I don't understand is how I do connect them correctly.

I have crated the grafic content and it looks like
[image]

How do I connect the 3 classes with each other? Have I done it correctly or missing something?
And how do I get a respons when I am pressing the game panel?? I do believe I am calling the functions correctly, but since it's not working I guess not.

This is View:

```
    package test;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.util.*;

    public class View  extends JFrame{
    
    Random random = new Random(); 
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(); 
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JPanel gamePanel = new JPanel(); 
    JLabel txt = new JLabel();
    JButton[] btns = new JButton[9]; 
    // this is going to be true, if player 1 is false than player 2 starts 
     boolean player; 

         Controller controller; 
         Model  model;

    
        public View (Controller controller, Model model){
            this.model = model;
            this.controller = controller;

            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(700,700);
        //  frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(50,50,50));
            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            
            // the img at the buttom of the frame 
            Icon userIcon = new ImageIcon("tttlogo.png");
            JLabel userLabel = new JLabel(userIcon, JLabel.CENTER);
            frame.add(userLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            
        // this is the menu deisgn 
    //      txt.setBackground(Color.RED);
//          txt.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
//          txt.setFont(new Font("Ink Free",Font.BOLD,18));
            txt.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
//          txt.setText("Tic-Tac-Toe");  

            txt.setText("Player O Score:   It's " +  player + "Turn Player X Score: " ); 
            txt.setOpaque(true);

        // black background on the menu bar thing 
            panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            panel.setBounds(0,0,800,800);

        // make sure that the panels are places correctly 
            gamePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
        // this is just the color. 
            gamePanel.setBackground(new Color(150,150,150));
        
            panel.add(txt); 
            frame.add(panel,BorderLayout.NORTH); 
            frame.add(gamePanel);
            
            frame.setVisible(true);

                for(int i=0; i<9;i++) {
                    btns[i] = new JButton();
                    gamePanel.add(btns[i]);
                    btns[i].setFont(new Font("MV Boli", Font.BOLD,120));
                    btns[i].setFocusable(false);
                    btns[i].setActionCommand("X");
                    btns[i].addActionListener(controller);
                }
                model.firstTurn(); 
                model.check();
            }
    }
```

This is Model:

```
package test;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Model{
    
    // textfield the mark if it's X or O that are placeing it 
        private JButton btns = new JButton();
        private JLabel txt = new JLabel();
        private Random random = new Random();

        Boolean player = true; 
        int size;
        int [][] board;


    public  void firstTurn() {

        System.out.println("MEEEEEEE ");
        if(random.nextInt(2)==0) {
            player=true;
            txt.setText("X turn");
        }
        else {
            player=false;
            txt.setText("O turn");
        }
    }

    public boolean check(){
    System.out.println("Check ");
        boolean leftWin = true;
        boolean rightWin = true;


        for(int j = 1; j < this.size; j++){
            boolean colWin = true;
            boolean rowWin = true;
            for(int i =0; i < this.size; i++){
                colWin = colWin && (board[i][j] == board[i][j-1]);
                rowWin = rowWin && (board[j][i] == board[j-1][i]);
            }
            if ((rowWin && board[j][0] != -1) || (colWin && board[0][j] != -1)){
                return true;
            }
            leftWin = leftWin  && (board[j][j] == board[j-1][j-1]);
            rightWin = leftWin  && (board[this.size - j][j] == board[this.size - j+1][j-1]);
        }
        return (rightWin && board[0][0] != -1) || (leftWin && board[this.size-1][0] != -1);
    }
  
public static void main(String []args){ 

    Model model = new Model(); 
   Controller controller = new Controller(model); 
  View view = new View(controller , model); 
    //View view = new View (controller); 
    controller.setView(view); 
//  Model view = new Model ();
//  new View();
    /*
    Model model = new Model(); 
    Controller controller = new Controller(model); 
    View view = new view( controller , model ); 
    new v();
    */
    
}

}
```

This is the Controller:

```
package test;

import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Controller extends WindowAdapter implements ActionListener{

    private View view; 
    private Model model;

        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel(); 
        JLabel textfield = new JLabel();
        JButton[] btns = new JButton[9]; 
        boolean player; 
        Controller controller; 

    public Controller(View view, Model model) {
        this.view = view;
        this.model = model;

    }

    public void setView(View view) {
        this.view = view; 
}

public Controller(Controller controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
}



public Controller(Model model) {
    this.model = model; 

}

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

   System.out.println("Pretyt"); 
        for(int i=0; i<9; i++) {
            System.out.println("pj"); 
        if(event.getActionCommand().equals(btns[i]))
            {
                    System.out.println("coffe"); 
                if(player) {
                    if(btns[i].getText()=="") {
                        btns[i].setText("X");
                        player=false; 
                        textfield.setText("O turn");
                        model.check();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if(btns[i].getText()=="") {
                        btns[i].setText("O");
                        player=true; 
                        textfield.setText("X turn");
                        model.check();  
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}

        
    }
```

Comment: The fact that all the layers have swing components in them make this look like *not* being developed accordingly to the MVC pattern. I'd say connecting them is the least of the problems here.

Comment: As an aside, when asking questions here please don't just dump the code as is. For example we don't really care for all the commented code. No need to post it.

Comment: I agree with @FedericoklezCulloca: Only the view should be responsible for creating Swing components. The model should be as GUI-library agnostic as possible, and should be usable for most any UI set up, including as a model for a console program. Your design appears to be broken.

Comment: Side note, this, `if(btns[i].getText()=="") {` is not safe. Don't compare Strings using `==` or `!=`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that `==` checks if the two *object references* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.  Better would be, ``if (btns[i].getText().trim().isEmpty()) {``

Comment: The model consists of one or more plain Java getter/setter classes.  The view consists of one `JFrame` and as many `JPanels` as necessary.  The controllers are the actions or listeners.

Answer (score -1):

No you are doing it wrong first of all all the logic of the game should be in the controller the model should only have the board stored as a array,so if i would approach this i would create a class called GameBoard that extends java observable

```
  public class GameBoard extends observable{
char[] board;
    
GameBoard(){
    this.board = new char[9];
}
// all of the logic as methods
}
```

then what i would do is pass this class as argument of the constructor of JFrame and would make the JFrame implement the observer interface

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).